# copying and replacing files in uwp

Tags: c#, list, uwp, storagefile, storagefolder

I am creating an app and one of the requirements for the app was to be able to allow the users to change the data that the app has access to by means of changing a folder in the documents folder and pressing an update button. 1. This app will not have access to the internet. 2. Accessing the Documents folder is a specific request(i know uwp is sand-boxed) 3. Essentially I'm trying to moves files from a folder in the documents storage to local storage without the path(since I dont have access to it). This is my attempt at it.

```
 class  Copy
      {
         public async void update()
    {

        FolderPicker openPicker = new FolderPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");


        StorageFolder updatefolder = await openPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            //CreateFileAsync("sample.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        // Do something with the new file.

        // Get the app's local folder to use as the destination folder.
        StorageFolder mainFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;



        // Set options for file type and sort order.
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
        queryOptions.IndexerOption = IndexerOption.OnlyUseIndexer;

        // Get the files in the user's document folder
        // and its subfolders and sort them by date.
        StorageFileQueryResult results = updatefolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);



        // Iterate over the results and print the list of files
        // to the Visual Studio Output window.
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sortedFiles = await results.GetFilesAsync();
        sortedFiles.ToList<StorageFile>();

        foreach (StorageFile item in sortedFiles)
        {


                StorageFile copiedFile = await item.CopyAsync(mainFolder, item.DisplayName, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);


        }

    }
    }


}
```

This kind of works. When I call the update method, the files copy but don't replace even though I have the `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting` option for  `CreateFileAsync`. Also the thumbnails  don't transfer over and even though it has the same memory the computer can't recognize what type of file it is. Here is a screenshot.[Destination Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q63Vb.png) I thought it was due to the list being readonly so I tried explicitly converting it into a list but I received the same result. I'm so close and I just need a little assistance. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use item.Name in your item.CopyAsync(..) Method instead of item.DisplayName. Maybe have a look at theStorageFile.CopyAndReplaceAsync(IStorageFile) method as well.

Comment: @Hannes that actually worked!!! I'm kind of mad it was so simple. Took forever to troubleshoot